# Excluding foreign key attributes causes nested queries to fail

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

On all my models I have a created by and updated by foreign key columns that link to my user model. When I query my database using findAll() for example, I always include them so that the user's username and other details are returned with my results - I also exclude the foreign key columns for the result at it makes no sense returning the created by object which includes the ID and and the createdById node as it's just duplicate data

```
"createdById": "21499bb6-4476-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77",
"createdBy": {
    "id": "21499bb6-4476-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77",
    "username": "mo.gusbi"
},
"updatedById": "21499bb6-4476-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77",
"updatedBy": {
    "id": "21499bb6-4476-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77",
    "username": "mo.gusbi"
}
```

So what I do is just exclude `createdById` and `updatedById` attributes and this works great, until I have to join other tables and include constraints (for pagination, that cause a subquery to be generated) which looks for the `createdById` and `updatedById` columns that I originally excluded, causing an SQL error

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: Category.createdById
```

from the generated query

```
SELECT `Category`.*, `children`.`id` AS `children.id`,
  `children`.`name` AS `children.name`,
  `createdBy`.`id` AS `createdBy.id`,
  `createdBy`.`username` AS `createdBy.username`,
  `updatedBy`.`id` AS `updatedBy.id`,
  `updatedBy`.`username` AS `updatedBy.username`,
  `deletedBy`.`id` AS `deletedBy.id`,
  `deletedBy`.`username` AS `deletedBy.username`
FROM (
  SELECT `Category`.`id`,
    `Category`.`name`,
    `Category`.`parentId`
  FROM `Categories` AS `Category`
  WHERE (`Category`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
    AND `Category`.`parentId` = NULL)
  LIMIT 0, 10
) AS `Category`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Categories` AS `children`
  ON `Category`.`id` = `children`.`parentId`
    AND `children`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Users` AS `createdBy`
  ON `Category`.`createdById` = `createdBy`.`id`
    AND `createdBy`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Users` AS `updatedBy`
  ON `Category`.`updatedById` = `updatedBy`.`id`
    AND `updatedBy`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Users` AS `deletedBy`
  ON `Category`.`deletedById` = `deletedBy`.`id`
    AND `deletedBy`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
;
```

**Models**

```
User = sequelize.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
      is: regex.username
    }
  }
}, {
  paranoid: true,
  classMethods: {
    associate: (models) => {
      User.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'createdById',
        as: 'createdBy'
      });

      User.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'updatedById',
        as: 'updatedBy'
      });

      User.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'deletedById',
        as: 'deletedBy'
      });
    }
  }
});

Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  }
}, {
  indexes: [{
    unique: true,
    fields: ['name', 'parentId']
  }],
  paranoid: true,
  classMethods: {
    associate: (models: any) => {
      Category.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'createdById',
        as: 'createdBy'
      });

      Category.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'updatedById',
        as: 'updatedBy'
      });

      Category.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'deletedById',
        as: 'deletedBy'
      });

      Category.belongsTo(models.Category, {
        foreignKey: 'parentId',
        as: 'parent'
      });

      Category.hasMany(models.Category, {
        foreignKey: 'parentId',
        as: 'children'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Query**

```
Category
  .findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'name',
      'parentId'
    ],
    where: {
      parentId: req.query.parentId
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: Category,
        as: 'children',
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'name'
        ]
      },
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'createdBy',
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'username'
        ]
      },
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'updatedBy',
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'username'
        ]
      },
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'deletedBy',
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'username'
        ]
      }
    ],
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
});
```

Comment: How would you expect your subquery to work without the information it's querying for?

Comment: Is there some way of leaving those foreign key fields in there without them being returned in the result other than going over the JSON result object and removing them after? Or better still, not use subqueries - which it only does when you introduce the offset and limit params